# Erasing duplicates from nested map (k-core algorithm)

Tags: c++, cluster-analysis, unordered-map, erase, unordered-set

i am trying to finish a homework and came with an error.
What i am trying to do is: There is an unordered map with keys containing values as unordered_set which may have keys inside that "may have the same names as keys of unordered outer map".

To be spesific, i am trying to implement a k-core algorithm, the count and k numbers are there for it. I am trying to erase unordered_map keys (lets call P) that have unordered_sets(containing neighbors, call N) which have lower than k sizes.
But since i delete the N entry from the P node, i also need to find the N entry from the outer map and find P and delete it there.

The following code is what i came up with so far (there is more but i don't want plagiarism or anything). During the debugging i noticed that somewhat  cout<<nodes.size() never executes. I don't know what is the problem. Probably the inner while infinitely loops, and it is related with how iterators function with erase etc. but i am not sure. Hope it is clear.

EDIT : I have updated the code according to the suggestion, but there is a new problem: for k=1 the amount of nodes are right. But after k=2,3,4.. there is infinite loop of outermost loop. And the size stays constant (after taking out nodes with k=1)

```
while(nodes.size()!=0)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(stillLeft){
        stillLeft = 0;
        it = nodes.begin();
        while(it != nodes.end()){
            
            if(it->second.size()<=k){
                stillLeft = 1;
                ++count;
                for ( innerit = it->second.begin(); innerit != it->second.end();innerit++ ){
                    nodes.find(*innerit)->second.erase(it->first);

                }
                it = nodes.erase(it);
                }
            else{
                ++it;
            }
                                    }
            
            }
        
    
    cout << nodes.size() << endl;
        
    kCoreNumbers.push_back(count);      
    ++k;
}
```

Comment: Tried debugging it at [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)?

Comment: Also, is something like this what you're working on `{{1, {1, 2}}, {5, {6, 1, 7}}}`, so if  `k= 2`, you delete the node `1` and now you also need to remove it from the neighbours list of node `5` to make it `{5, {6,7}` (which needs to be deleted again?

Comment: @Zoso yes exactly. I haven't tried the online debugger because i don't know how to use a debugger tool. I only debug with cout lines.

Comment: Looks like you're erasing the node that `P` refers to. This can break the for loop iteration. You should use a for loop (not a range-based for loop) and manually track the iterator in `nodes`. This would also avoid having to re-lookup the iterator you want to erase, because you'll already have it (and can properly update it when you do erase it).

Comment: I have updated the code but there is a new error, i can't find the reason why it happens. Thank you for suggestion though, it works a little better @1201ProgramAlarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop till `while(nodes.size()!=0)` i.e. till `nodes` is empty. After running the `k-core` algorithm, you might be left with nodes whose vertexes have a degree greater than `k`. You only need to loop till there are no more nodes that have a degree less than `k`.

Your initial code was in the right direction but with the problem of deleting a node in the map while traversing it. I solved it by just adding the vertices to be deleted to a vector while iterating the graph and then after each graph traversal just deleted all the nodes makred for deletion. Here's my version of code, based off yours with a few variable name changes to reflect what they are:

```
void runKCore(size_t k) {
    bool nodesDeleted;
    do {
        // To keep track of how many times the loop needs to run
        nodesDeleted = false;
        // To keep track of the nodes to be deleted after one pass
        std::vector<int> markDeleted;
        for(auto const& node: graph) {
            auto vertex = node.first;
            auto const& neighbours = node.second;
            // Pick vertex if it has less than k neighbours
            if(neighbours.size() < k) {
                for(auto neighbour: neighbours) {
                    // Get the neighbour's list of vertices
                    auto& neighBoursEdges = graph.at(neighbour);
                    // Remove vertex from this list
                    neighBoursEdges.erase(vertex);
                }
                // Mark this node as deleted
                markDeleted.push_back(vertex);
            }
        }
        // Update nodesDeleted if any nodes were marked for deletion
        nodesDeleted = markDeleted.size() > 0;
        for(auto node: markDeleted) {
            // Erase the node and it's neighbours
            graph.erase(node);
        }
    }while(nodesDeleted);
}
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6d5d7d442d51d38) is the complete program.

For an initial graph

[image]

translating to initial graph

```
8: 6 5 
7: 6 3 4 
6: 7 3 8 5 4 2 
5: 8 6 2 1 
4: 7 3 6 2 
3: 7 6 4 2 
2: 6 3 4 5 1 0 
1: 5 2 0 
0: 2 1
```

the output of the program after running the k-core algo for `k = 3` output is:

```
7: 6 3 4 
6: 7 3 4 2 
4: 7 3 6 2 
3: 7 6 4 2 
2: 6 3 4
```